# change value in pandas dataframe based on length of current value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that has a certain column that should have values of a length of four. If the length is three, I would like to add a '0' to the beginning of the value. For example:

```
a    b    c    
1    2    0054
3    6    021
5    5    0098
8    2    012
```

So in column c I would like to change the second row to '0021' and last row to '0012.' The values are already strings. I've tried doing:

```
 df.loc[len(df['c']) == 3, 'c'] = '0' + df['c']
```

but it's not working out. Thanks for any help!

Comment: basically you can just do `df['c'] = df['c'].str.zfill(4)`

Answer (score 1):

If the type in `C` is *int* you can do something like this:

```
df['C'].apply(lambda x: ('0'*(4-len(str(x))))+str(x) if(len(str(x)) < 4) else str(x))
```

In the lambda function, I check whether the number of digits/characters in `x` is less than four. If yes, I add zeros in front, so that the number of digits/characters in `x` will be four (this is also known as *padding*). If not, I return the value as string.

In case your type is string, you can remove the `str()` function calls, but it will work either way.